# How to parse a file sentence by sentence in Python

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I need to read a large amount of large text files.

For each file, I need to open it and read in text sentence by sentence.

Most of approaches I found is read line by line.

How can I do it with Python?

Comment: fyi. sentence tokenization is not a simple feat. NLTK is one of the gold standard libraries to accomplish this, and has pretrained models to do it. If this helped. please mark as answer :) Cheers

Comment: Define "sentence" in your use case.

Comment: @Joel: I understand that you ask to build the rule to extract sentence. But unlucky that there are many rules such as titles (Mr., Mrs.) , location (Dist., Ward., St.) or even in name (Sant.). We even cannot list out all the rules, but we definitly recognise thm when we see

Comment: @PeterPhan I understand. I was simply curious if your use case had some useful constraints which would allow you to split on ".", for example. If it is as you describe than use nltk tokenization as in the answers below.

Comment: @Joel, even we can use the tokenizer from nltk, we must load all text first, then we tokenize them into sentence. This approach return correct result, but the problem I have got is heavy loading text because my text data is very large. That is why I need an approach to feed sentence by sentence, not load all and tokenize afterward.

Comment: Incorrect. You don't have to load _everything_. Load in line by line (use python's `f.readline()`. If you have a large document (like a novel) the line breaks would be paragraphs.Then parse each text into sentences. Basically, you can't parse something that isn't in memory, and there is no simple way to detect sentence boundries prior to loading unless you want to map your own rules for what counts as a sentence. There are a lot of them, as you point out, and NLTK is going to be your quickest bootstrap.  TLDR you can't "read a sentence" from a file the way you have constrained the problem.

Comment: @matisetorm you could buffer the data, say 1k, ahead of time. This would be one approach.

Comment: True, but there would need to be a lot of extra logic needed to check if the 1K cut off in the middle of the sentence. _AND_ as the OP has made abundantly clear, that isn't reading it in _by sentence_. The 1K buffer still means the data to be parsed has to be in memory first. If what the OP is saying is that he doesn't have manageable line breaks, then yes, reading in 1K at a time is the next logical step. _BUT_ that still doesn't allow him to "read it in" sentence by sentence. Throwing my hands up for the OP to clarify the question at this point

Comment: nltk and textblob both have feature of sentece tokenization. I think in near future, they will have upgrade some function call readsentence() to feed file sentence by sentence. I think it would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want sentence tokenization, nltk is probably the quickest way to do so. http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.punkt
Will get you pretty far.

i.e. code from docs

```
>>> import nltk.data
>>> text = '''
... Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
... do not mark sentence boundaries.  And sometimes sentences
... can start with non-capitalized words.  i is a good variable
... name.
... '''
>>> sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>> print('\n-----\n'.join(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip())))


Punkt knows that the periods in Mr. Smith and Johann S. Bach
do not mark sentence boundaries.
-----
And sometimes sentences
can start with non-capitalized words.
-----
i is a good variable
name.
```

Comment: There is no need to call `str.strip()`, the tokenizer will do the striping, anyway.

Comment: This is very good for extract sentence from text, but how to feed sentence by sentence from file?

Comment: You can't read sentence by sentence from a file. You have to parse it first.

Comment: You don't have to load everything. Load in line by line (use python's `f.readline()`). If you have a large document (like a novel) the line breaks would be paragraphs.Then parse each text into sentences. Basically, you can't parse something that isn't in memory, and there is no simple way to detect sentence boundries prior to loading unless you want to map your own rules for what counts as a sentence. There are a lot of them, as you point out, and NLTK is going to be your quickest bootstrap.

Comment: @PeterPhan So what did you land on? Any solutions to the problem. There have been 2-3 valid solutions provided

Comment: @matisetorm: Until now, I think your suggestion is the best solution. First, breakdown the document into papragraphs (by using NewLine char). Secondly, I tokenize each paragraph into sentences. I am implementing such steps to validate. I believe it work. BTW, I am not sure whether we can read paragraph one by one or not. I saw some code load all data to memory and split into paragraghs. About read line by line, it is almost imposible because a sentence may take 2 lines or least than a line.

Comment: Yes, some data like a novel for each file. I am building a search engine based on my algorithm for arround 200k file.

Answer (score -2):

If the files have large amounts of lines you could make a generator using the yield statement

```
def read(filename):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

for word in read("sample.txt"):
    print word
```

This would return all the words of each line of the file

Comment: Not what he asked

Comment: Oh, this return list of words, not list of sentences

Comment: @PeterPhan Technically, not even a list of words. `str.split()` is a poor natural language tokenizer.